# WinRT Progress Indicator implement 500ms wait to prevent flickering

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a windows phone 8.1 app that uses indeterminate progress indicators to show users that a web
request is being done. Most of the time the request finishes in less than a second causing the progress indicator to briefly appear.

Anyone got any suggestions on how I should implement this. I have tried to the following code from [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/ce907f1e-5eb7-4d59-80f5-7cab913c332d/prevent-progress-bar-flickering-by-adding-wait) discussion but it doesn't seem that "clean" because I get compile time warnings that I am not using the await keyword.

```
Task threatScoreTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    //code    
});
Task locationTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    //code    
});
Task results = Task.WhenAll(threatScoreTask, locationTask);
Task.Delay(500).ContinueWith(async e => 
{ 
   if (!results.IsCompleted)  
       //code to turn on progress bar
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually now that I think about it, the code looks fine.

If you want to get rid of the warning, you can assign it to a variable like this -

```
var delay = Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(e =>
```

Comment: But then what if the task finish in less than 250ms, it will just wait for 250ms.

Comment: Great, and I assume that I will use this delay task to check if I should disable the progress indicator